# create directive for th tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to create directive that will simplify HTML.
Now html Look like:

```
        <tr>
            <th class="span3" ng-click="setSorting('status')" ng-class="columnClass('status')">
                title1 
                <div class="sorted-image"> 
                    <i ng-class="iconClass('status')"></i> 
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="span4" ng-click="setSorting('sensorIdOrder')" ng-class="columnClass('sensorIdOrder')">
                title2 
                <div class="sorted-image"> 
                    <i ng-class="iconClass('sensorIdOrder')"></i> 
                </div>
            </th>
            <th class="span3">
                title3 
            </th>
        </tr>
```

Where setSorting is function for sorting and set value that use in ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in getData()| orderBy : sorting.field : !sorting.asc">
```

I want create thsort directive, that contain all function(setSorting, columnClass, iconClass) and use only one argument argument

```
        <tr>
            <thsort class="span3" sort-field = "status")">
                title1 
            </thsort>
            <thsort class="span4" sort-field = "sensorIdOrder">
                title2 
            </thsort>
            <th class="span3">
                title3 
            </th>
        </tr>
```

also all argument (Like argument) after compile applied to

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unnecessary try to create the sort directive. You can use [ng-Grid directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/),there support sort,custom theme and many usefull function.